# NodeJS: Unable to verify JWT with Okta JWT Verifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, okta, okta-api

I am trying to verify a JWT token sent from a frontend app using  the @okta/jwt-verifier package.I keep getting the below error

```
JwtParseError: Error while resolving signing key for kid "kp2hms0pqlMsflp34dc"
innerError: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

The credentials I am using are similar to the below

```
OKTA_AUDIENCE = 'api://default'
OKTA_CLIENT_ID = '0psnmdjeuti34spl8'
OKTA_ISSUER = 'https://dev-04567220.okta.com/oauth2/default'

const OktaJwtVerifier = require('@okta/jwt-verifier');
const oktaJwtVerifier = new OktaJwtVerifier({
  issuer: OKTA_ISSUER ,
  clientId: OKTA_CLIENT_ID 
});

oktaJwtVerifier.verifyAccessToken(token, OKTA_AUDIENCE )
.then(jwt => {
  // the token is valid (per definition of 'valid' above)
  console.log(jwt.claims);
})
.catch(err => {
  // a validation failed, inspect the error
});
```

What exactly am I doing wrong ?

Comment: is this error raised inside `catch` block?

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev Yes this error occurs inside the catch block

Comment: This probably mean, that your token is not correct. Based on the error description, the key used to sign the token, is not present at authZ server. So I think that nothing wrong is with your code, but with your token

Comment: Is there any other way I can verify the Okta Token?

Comment: I don't think you are doing something wrong. It's maybe the token doesn't pass validate. Did you try to inspect it manually to see that all the parameters inside it are fine? See the answer from @alisaduncan below to find out what is/should validated

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [developer documentation on how to verify a token from Okta](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/protect-your-api/nodeexpress/main/#require-authorization-for-everything).

Some things to double-check

1. Your Audience, Client ID, and Issuer are correct and matches how the front-end gets the token
2. You are only verifying the token (so the `Bearer`  text is removed)
3. The front-end is sending you the correct token, the Access token